# Android - How to get the image resource to use in if statement

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

So I set a `onClick` listener to my `ImageView` via the xml file. It's called changeImage(). In that, I want it to be so:

```
if(img.getImageResource == R.drawable.1){
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.2);
}else if(img.getImageResource == R.drawable.2){
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.1)
}
```

Only the problem is, there's no such thing as getImageResource. How do I do it?

**EDIT:**

```
public void changeImage(View v) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
    Drawable drawable = img.getDrawable();

    if(drawable == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lightbulb_off)){
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }else if(drawable == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)){
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lightbulb_off);
    }
}
```

does not work. Why???????? :'(

Answer (score 0):

Calling Resources.getDrawable() returns a unique object each time, so == comparison will never return true. Drawables also don't generally implement Object.equals() in a way that would solve your issue either.

Instead, consider using a selector drawable as your image and ImageView.setSelected(boolean) to toggle between states.

res/drawable/lightbulb.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/lightbulb_off" />
</selector>
```

res/layout/your_layout.xml:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img" android:src="@drawable/lightbulb" />
```

In your code, toggle selection state.

```
public void changeImage(View v) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setSelected(!myImageView.isSelected());
}
```

Comment: Wait, what? drawable/lightbulb.xml? I thought the drawable folders were for images only...don't you mean layout?

Comment: You can create shape drawables, state list drawables, etc. using XML. Yes, they go in the drawable (with no config specifier) directory.

Comment: I tried, doesn't work. Can you exactly tell me how to implement the lightbulb.xml? All I've implemented were only layout xml's. Sorry, I'm sorta nooby.

Answer (score 0):

As alanv states, using a selector would work, where you'd be able to check the selected state of the ImageView.

I'd recommended separating your business logic from the UI though; e.g. create a `LightBulb` class which has a state of `ON` or `OFF`. Instead of relying on the current state of the ImageView when toggling, you'd just check the state of your `lightBulb`:

```
private void toggleSwitch() {
    lightBulb.toggleSwitch();
    updateLightBulbImage();
}

private void updateLightBulbImage() {
    if (lightBulb.isSwitchedOn()) {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.switched_on);
    } else {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.switched_off);
    }
}
```